# Adding Scope to ActiveAdmin routes getting ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, activeadmin

I'm attempting to add a scope to the ActiveAdmin routes so that I can include the '/:brand' within the URL.  SO instead of `localhost:3000/admin/dashboard` it would be `localhost:3000/bg/admin/dashboard`, with the bg being the brand.

I have my routes.rb setup like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/:brand', brand: /bg|gwt|acf/ do
    devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  end
end
```

The route for logging in `http://localhost:3000/bg/admin/login` works perfectly fine.  But once logged in I'm getting the below error for any ActiveAdmin resource.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/dashboard"} missing required keys: [:brand]):
    actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:50:in `generate'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:629:in `generate'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:660:in `generate'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:707:in `url_for'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:236:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
/Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f8926831429f/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:40:in `root_path'
devise (4.2.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:178:in `signed_in_root_path'
devise (4.2.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:214:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:114:in `require_no_authentication'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack-timeout (0.4.2) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:122:in `block in call'
rack-timeout (0.4.2) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
rack-timeout (0.4.2) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:121:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendering /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendering /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (103.9ms)
source=rack-timeout id=da53bfbfe078024cf2939732b0756051 timeout=3100000ms service=578ms state=completed
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening or a way to get around it?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do any of these help? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UrlGenerationError

Comment: @PiersC Sadly none of those help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.  Feel a bit silly about this, but I was using a forked repo of the original ActiveAdmin.  When I switched over to use the latest from the original ActiveAdmin everything works exactly like I expected it to.

Just in case someone runs into the same issue, I was using https://github.com/dtaniwaki/active_admin, which hasnt' been updated in over 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is telling you that no route exists for the url you are trying to visit. 

`No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/dashboard"} missing required keys: [:brand]`

Specifically, you're missing the `:brand`.

Where are you redirecting to after successful sign in?

It should look something like `admin_root_path(brand: 'bg')`. And every path helper you invoke will need to specify that `:brand` param.

Comment: OK, I gave this a try and I'm still having a similar issue, though slightly different.  What I did was add after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope) to my application controller and if the resource_or_scope.class == AdminUser, then I call admin_root_path(brand: params[:brand]).  I still get the same ActionControlller::UrlGenerationError in Admin::Dashboard#index, but the No route matches it pointing to a different admin controller which I'm not even trying to go to in this request.
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/other_controller"} missing required keys: [:brand]

Comment: Strange. Have you used a pry or byebug before the redirect to inspect the path? What does your `rake routes | grep admin_root` show?

Comment: The route is what I was expecting it to be. `admin_root GET        /:brand/admin(.:format)                                                                            admin/dashboard#index {:brand=>/bg|gwt|acf/}`.  The fullpath right before the redirect is `/bg/admin/login` and afterwards in the dashboard controller index it's `/bg/admin`.  In the params I see `'brand' = "bg"`.

Comment: I don't know why you would be getting `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/other_controller"}` unless you have some other redirection logic that is happening after the it redirects to `admin_root`. I'd suggest watching your server logs and trying it again - it should show all redirections that happen, maybe there is one in your `admin/dashboard#index`, or a `before_action` somewhere higher up the chain that is redirecting?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  The forked repo I was using is what caused the issue.  I added my answer in case anyone else runs into the issue, but I'm going to reward the bounty to you.

Comment: Ah, well that explains why you were getting errors that made absolutely no sense... Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes indicates there is some error in some path definition,

I was defining the wrong path for the logout path for the admin session and thus got this error.